# Load javascript in android WebView without loadUrl()

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to run some javascript in an android web view.  I understand this works fine by loading a javascript: url.  It seems that when I do that though the selected text in the web view is cleared.  The javascript I'm running gets the range of the selected text, so I need it to remain selected.

How can I run the javascript without losing the selection?

Answer (score -1):

to make your webview be able to run Javascript do this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: I have those set and I can run javascript by doing webView.loadUrl("javascript: something"); But that clears any user selection.  I need to keep that user selection and use it in my javascript.